# Bootsrap vertical bottom inside a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I place the img to the bottom of the div?

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: yellow; height: 600px;">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="img.png" alt="alt">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                Lorem ipsum
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: It is at the bottom of the div. Do you want it at the bottom of the *parent* `div`?

Comment: I want this: http://jan.imghost.us/4xLQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 myclass">
    <img src="img.png" class="bottom" width="300">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .bottom{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
    }

    .myclass{
        height: 100%;
        position:relative;
    }
```